# AMD Ryzen 7 5700u CPU capped at 400 MHz in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, cpu, amd-processor, frequency

Recently I was doing some benchmarks in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and I realized that even though my CPU is supposed to work at a base frequency of 1.8 GHz it only works at 400 MHz, the baseline for battery saver. I have a dual boot and tried to check on the frequency on Windows 11 and it works just fine. Any idea why this may be?

For specs my laptop is the MSI Modern 15 A5M-009XES

Comment: Under Settings/Power, what power mode and options are selected?

Comment: I already checked and it's in standard